# Android AsyncTask getting an exception null

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

In the AsyncTask android. When calling a method in another class gets an exception which equals to null in the doInBackGround() task.

Even the hard coded inside the rest.request(url, method, json) doesn't work

```
       protected JSONArray doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            try {
                return rest.request(url, method, json);  // <-- returns json array
            } catch (Exception e) {
                this.e = e; 
            }
            return null; // <--- returning this null

        }
```

Other things are like this,

```
private class doRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, JSONArray, JSONArray>
protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray data)


/*rest client class*/
public class AndrestClient {

// The client to use for requests
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
public JSONArray request(String url, String method, String json) throws RESTException {
        if (method.matches("GET")) {
            return get(url);
        } else if (method.matches("POST")) {
            return post(url, json);
        } else if (method.matches("PUT")) {
            //return put(url, data);
        } else if (method.matches("DELETE")) {
            //return delete(url);
        }
        throw new RESTException("Error! Incorrect method provided: " + method);
    }

    public JSONArray get(String url) throws RESTException {

        String jsonjr = "['Chanuthi','Damsith','Dunili','Isath','Minuka','Uvin','Vidath']";

        JSONArray jsonAraay = null;
        try {
            jsonAraay = new JSONArray(jsonjr);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return jsonAraay;
}
}
```

The exception I got is e=null. All the other things work properly. When I am hard coding the result inside in the doInBackGround it works properly. Also the rest client get method returns the exact thing.

Comment: provide more code so that we can help you, also please post the stack trace of the exception and in which line exactly does it occur.

Comment: where is the `rest`'s request method defined?  Also, where are url, method and json defined?

Comment: Actually, your question text and your code comments contradict.  If you're getting an exception of null, then you can't be returning null naturally as in your code comment. So which is it?

Comment: if there is an exception it will return null, if its successful it will return a jsonarray, from what i see.. the returning null naturally is just to satisfy the logic 'else' of his code.. so basically if your code returns null, it could be there was an exception, but since you dont have `e.printStackTrace()` its caught but not outputted.. this goes to both OP and @MiiinimalLogic .. im too dizzy to keep up context..sorry for that

Comment: OP, you know you have to subclass your AsyncTask right?  It looks like you're not doing that.

Comment: Now I have provided more information. No if I got an exception only it returns the null. but it self it shows an exception which equals to null. But when I hard coded the result inside the doInBackgroud it works properly.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're using AsyncTask improperly.  Firstly,  you *must* subclass/nest your AsyncTask as per the Android documentation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

In addition, you should follow the fundamental rules for calling methods of an outter class from a nested class.

There are some alternatives, like:

- Create the AndrestClient object in onPreExecute() of the AsyncTask
- Pass the AndrestClient object to the doInBackground as a parameter, then call its methods by doing something like this in the outter class:

  doRequest.execute(rest);